# Replace string with variable of the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Outside of a `$.each()` loop, I have: `var $address = xyz`

Inside of a `$.each()` loop, I have: `var $string = "_address"`

Inside this `$.each()` loop, I need to replace `$string` with `$address`, but it's on a `$.each()` loop, so I need to do the same with `$state`, `$zip`, etc.

The code:

```
$("input.changed.address, select.changed.address").each(function(){
    var edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var main_id = edit_id.substr(5);
    main_id_same_variable_name = (serialized_changes.filter(function (field) { 
        return field.name == edit_id 
    })[0]['value']);
});
```

Is being modeled from what I did earlier here:

```
$("input.changed:not(.address), select.changed:not(.address)").each(function(){
    var edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var main_id = edit_id.substr(5);
    $('#' + main_id).text(serialized_changes.filter(function (field) { 
        return field.name == edit_id 
    })[0]['value']);
});
```

But I don't have the luxury of using a div ID like I did directly above ^^, I need to change a global variable in the first code snippet.

Comment: show us the code too..

Comment: Provide us with ur code sample

Comment: I hope I'm being clear enough!

Comment: Wow. I just have to use an array instead of different variables for city, state, zip, etc.... I'll post answer in a sec